# X-Content-Type-Options without content-type

Tags: http, header

[`X-Content-Type-Options`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#x-content-type-options-header) helps to protect against attacks that take advantage of the browser trying to interpret HTTP responses with an incorrectly stated `Content-Type`.

But what happens when the HTTP response sets the `X-Content-Type-Options` header but not the `Content-Type` header.

Will the browser still "sniff" or will it take a certain default?

Comment: According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options), `nosniff only applies to "script" and "style" types` therefore it shouldn't have any effect when no content type is specified - the browser can still sniff. Internet Explorer/Edge seems most vulnerable to script tags being embedded in responses without a content types se.

Comment: I dont enterily understand. Can you elaborate in an answer?

Comment: According to the link I posted, `nosniff` only affects script and style content types. In the case of no content type then Internet Explorer will sniff and read script tags and execute them.

Comment: Indeed, seems to be a Firefox and Chrome implementation https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/395 But they also mention that this is not following the specs.

Comment: Exactly. Before reading the Mozilla link I would have pointed you in this direction: https://blog.fox-it.com/2012/05/08/mime-sniffing-feature-or-vulnerability/ / https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms775147(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: For IE nosniff is pretty strict, it would reject a PNG if it has content-type jpeg.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer on the same [page](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-x-content-type-options):

> 1. Let mimeType be the result of extracting a MIME type from response’s
>      header list.
> 2. Let destination be request’s destination.
> 3. If destination is script-like and mimeType (ignoring parameters) is not
>      a JavaScript MIME type, then return blocked.
> 4. If destination is "style" and mimeType (ignoring parameters) is not `text/css`, then return blocked.
> 5. Return allowed.

I assume, since there is no MIME type declared, step 3 never returns blocked. In my case, there is no destination either, so we finish in step 5 -> allowed.

Edit: In step 3 and 4 an empty mime-type will not be a javascript mime type or a text/css mime-type. Therefor the request will be blocked if the destination matches.